# How to use dc.js and crossfilter with aurelia-cli

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter, aurelia

I am trying to import dc.js and crossfilter with aurelia-cli and have the following issue:

When I import dc and crossfilter in app.js both the exported entities are available: the 'dc' object and the crossfilter function, so I have no problem creating a chart and creating a crossfilter index and subsequent dimensions. The issue arises when rendering the chart: the dc library assumes a global crossfilter function but it turns out to be an object crossfilter that *has* a function crossfilter (`crossfilter.crossfilter`)

An error shown is "Cannot read property 'by' of undefined" in the dc library:

```
_chart._computeOrderedGroups = function (data) {
    ...
    if (!_orderSort) {
        _orderSort = crossfilter.quicksort.by(_ordering);
    }

    return _orderSort(dataCopy, 0, dataCopy.length);
};
```

Below are snippets from aurelia.json and the imports from app.js
Which alterations do I have to make to get it all working together?

aurelia.json

```
"dependencies": [
...
{
        "name": "dc",
        "path": "../node_modules/dc/dc",
        "deps": ["d3","crossfilter"]
      },
      {
        "name": "d3",
        "path": "../node_modules/d3/d3",
      },
      {
        "name": "crossfilter",
        "path": "../node_modules/crossfilter/crossfilter"            
      }
```

app.js

```
import * as dc from 'dc';
import {crossfilter} from 'crossfilter';
```

I also tried:

```
import * as dc from 'dc';
import * as crossfilter from 'crossfilter';
```

Comment: Oh yay another bundler I hadn't heard of. We actually already have [a workaround for the same problem in browserify](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/footer.js#L28), but I guess aurelia probably hits the AMD code path not the Node code path (?)

Comment: Actually aurelia-cli offers a wide range of solutions to include als sorts of libraries (configurable in aurelia.json) and it's aware of the dependencies in the framework. The link you gave is interesting, though. I'll have a look.

Comment: Hmm if that's so, you might be able to configure it to load dc.js as a Node module instead of AMD. If not, you could implement the same workaround in the if-block above the one I linked, and please submit a pull request. This code winds up at the end of dc.js. Lmk if you run into trouble.

Comment: We've abandoned aurelia-cli in favor of webpack, The path you suggested @Gordon could well resolve the issue (aurelia-cli requires a small change in the test), But I'd rather not patch a library or frame work for a new bundler, instead we chose a combination of framework and bundler that play nice together